# pandas filter entries by date

Tags: python, pandas, date

have a dataframe with a key named 'date'. first few entries look like this:

```
0    02.01.2013
1    03.01.2013
2    05.01.2013
3    06.01.2013
4    15.01.2013
```

Now i want to use pandas to filter out all the rows that are for example not 2014 as a date.

i looked through tutorials and find the following :

```
mask = transactions['date'][9]==4
trans=transactions[mask]
```

but that does not work since

```
transactions['date'][9]
```

gives me the 9th data entry but not the 9th digit of the date.

Can someone help a newb along ?

Comment: Hi, can you post your data frame code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df
         date
0  02.01.2013
1  03.01.2013
2  05.01.2013
3  06.01.2014
4  15.01.2014
```

Convert the column to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime`, and test the `dt.year` attribute -

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.year != 2014
m

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

Use the mask to filter on `df` -

```
df = df[m]
```

---

If the datetime column is the index, you'd instead need to convert the `df.index` -

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df.index).year != 2014
```